# Is it possible to make an asset http fetchable as part of a Jest test

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs

Is it possible to make a test asset (such as a pdf) accessible via http during a test run using Jest for a webpack project?

To give context, I'm writing a test for pdf.js api where normally I'd provide a http url. But when I run a test via Jest the file I'm providing is in the local filing system. Use of the "file" protocol with a relative path would be a CORs vialoation. If I were manually testing I could make it statically available as part of the wepback build, but of course I'm running a Jest test so that doesn't apply.

Added note: I bypassed http url problem by passing a blob represented in base64 into pdf.js getDocument. This solution works pretty well as the string is pretty succinct. However I'm still interested in figuring out how to access http resources through Jest in case I run into something like this again.

Comment: Expose your loader to a sepearted file. And mock it when you run tests. `getDocument` accepts both URL and `Uint8Array` data binary. You might use Node.js API to read the local PDF files as binary and load it into pdfjs.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a unit test, you shouldn't perform any http requests, but mock them instead, using something like `moxios`.

I recommend you to import a predefined example file from your filesystem and make the mocked http return its content.